# Wrap many similar cpp classes with Cython

Tags: c++, cython

I need to wrap similar cpp classes with Cython. I could just repeat many times what works for one class, i.e. something like:

```
from mycpplib import FFT2DWithFFTW1D as mycppclass

cdef class FFT2DWithFFTW1D:
    cdef mycppclass* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, int n0=2, int n1=2):
        self.thisptr = new mycppclass(n0, n1)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.thisptr.destroy()
        del self.thisptr

    def get_local_size_X(self):
        return self.thisptr.get_local_size_X()

    # many other functions...
```

To wrap the other classes, I basically have to write the same thing except the first line and maybe slight changes in one or two functions.

I naively thought that I could use a base class and do something like

```
class BaseFFT2D:
    def get_local_size_X(self):
        return self.thisptr.get_local_size_X()

    # many other functions...

cdef class FFT2DWithFFTW1D(BaseFFT2D):
    cdef mycppclass* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, int n0=2, int n1=2):
        self.thisptr = new mycppclass(n0, n1)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.thisptr.destroy()
        del self.thisptr
```

but of course this does not work because `thisptr` is not a Python object. Since this is just a cpp pointer, I can not use the Cython keyword `public` to make it accessible to Python.

Is there a nicer solution than repeating the same code for each cpp class?

A bad solution would be to use the Cython keyword `include` to include the definitions of the functions but it is really quite ugly.

Comment: Sadly there isn't really a way of automatically generating wrappers for cython that I know of. If all of your c++ classes are relatively simple have you thought of looking into [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a solution for this in Cython (as far as I know, and I have looked a little bit before).  However, I think the following (untested, but I think basically right) mako based solution is pretty clean.  Mako is a python template engine that is normally used to generate web pages, but can be used to generate Python or Cython code as well.

```
<%!
cpp_wrappers = [('FFT2DWithFFTW1D', 'FFT2DWithFFTW1D', 'mycppclass'), 
                     ('OtherClass', 'OtherCppClass', 'OtherCppClass')]
%>

% for _, importname, cppname in cpp_wrappers:
from mycpplib import ${importname} as ${cppname}
% endfor

% for classname, _, cppname in cpp_wrappers:
cdef class ${classname}:
    cdef ${cppname}* thisptr

    def __cinit__(self, int n0=2, int n1=2):
        self.thisptr = new ${cppname}(n0, n1)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        self.thisptr.destroy()
        del self.thisptr

    def get_local_size_X(self):
        return self.thisptr.get_local_size_X()

    # many other functions...

% endfor
```

Basically, it's a mako template for the Cython code you want to write.  As I've written it, this should create the cdef class in your example (`FFT2DWithFFTW1D`) plus one additional cdef class, `OtherClass`, based on the c++ class `OtherCppClass` imported under its own name.  In this way you avoid writing out a long Cython file with a bunch of classes that are basically the same.

I like to have mako compile the template (to create that long cython file) as part of setup.py.  For example, I might have something based on the following minimal script (also untested, but gives the basic idea at least):

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

# Set which files will be compiled
mako_files = [('modulename.mako.pyx','modulename.pyx')]
cython_files = [('modulename', 'modulename.pyx')]

# Compile mako template(s)
lookup = TemplateLookup(directories = ['.'])
for template_file, output_file in mako_files:
    template = lookup.get_template(template_file)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(template.render())

# Compile Cython files
ext_modules = []
for module_name, file_name in cython_files:
    ext_modules.append(Extension(module_name, [file_name]))
ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)

# Standard setup stuff
opts = dict(name='mypackage',
            requires=['cython', 'mako'],
            ext_modules=ext_modules,
            cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(**opts)
```

Cython already adds an extra compilation stage, in which your .pyx file is compiled to c or c++.  This solution adds yet another stage before that, in which the mako template is compiled into a Cython file.  You can use arbitrary Python code with mako, so you can basically get as fancy as you want in terms of customizing the different classes.  For the case above, I think this use of mako may actually be an improvement in readability over a long file full of nearly identical wrappers.  However, readability could obviously be lost if things get too complicated.